# Use latent semantic analysis to understand if a document is about a topic

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, topic-modeling, lsa

This is an example of the use of latent semantic analysis. For simplicity I have considered 4 documents and 2 topics. The code I used is the following:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD
import pandas as pd

body = [
    'the quick brown fox',
    'the slow brown dog',
    'the quick red dog',
    'the lazy yellow fox'
]

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(use_idf=False, norm='l1')
bag_of_words = vectorizer.fit_transform(body)

svd = TruncatedSVD(n_components=2)
lsa = svd.fit_transform(bag_of_words)

topic_encoded_df = pd.DataFrame(lsa, index=['text_1', 'text_2', 'text_3', 'text_4'], columns=['topic_1', 'topic_2'])
```

`topic_encoded_df` is the data frame

```
        topic_1     topic_2
text_1  0.423726    0.074881
text_2  0.378963    -0.192278
text_3  0.378963    -0.192278
text_4  0.316547    0.360146
```

Again, this is a trivial case to understand what I did.
Is there a way to coherently say if, for example, `text_1` is about `topic_2` in a meaningful way? Or if `text_ 2` is about `topic_2`? I was thinking of something like Elbow method on column values (sorted in descending order), but I'm afraid negative signs may give wrong indications. Anyone have another idea?

Comment: So you're running dimensionality reduction on tf-idf vectors, then you assume that each element of the resulting array represents a topic. Why? If you want to know the probability of a text belonging to a topic you'd better run a soft clustering algorithm on the vectors.

Comment: Each array does not necessarily represent a topic. But if this happens, starting from that table, can we know if a document is about a specific topic? Clustering (for example K-means, which I have already tried) is not the most appropriate method in my opinion, as a document could belong to multiple topics.

Comment: The vectors just represent a point in an n-dimensional space, so you'll need an algorithm to decide which points belong to the same cluster. If you use [soft clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_clustering) you'll get probability scores for the clusters per text. You could, for example, use [HDBSCAN](https://hdbscan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basic_hdbscan.html) for clustering, where you can access the probabilities with the `probabilities_` attribute.

Comment: So should I try applying HDBSCAN to the matrix `topic_encoded_df`, right?

Comment: It takes a [feature array](https://hdbscan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=fit#hdbscan.hdbscan_.HDBSCAN.fit) as input, not a dataframe. So you can input `lsa`. PS it runs well on up to [50-100](https://hdbscan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#q-i-am-not-getting-the-claimed-performance-why-not) features, so no need to reduce dimensionality to 2.

Comment: I applied what was written in your HDBSCAN guide in a larger example (~200 documents, ~10000 words in the vocabulary and 100 topics). But if I type `clusterer.labels_` I get an array of -1, and if I type `clusterer.probabilities_` I get an array of 0. My code is just `clusterer = hdbscan.HDBSCAN()` and `clusterer.fit(lsa)`, as in the guide.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237029/discussion-between-rj-adriaansen-and-ljg).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the Intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info (applicable here as well).